# C++ multiset create from sorted vector

Tags: c++, set, multiset

I have sorted array:

```
vector<T*> arrs;
```

I have a multiset

```
multiset<T*, sp_t_less<T>> tr;
```

I have this:

```
tr.erase();
tr.insert(arrs.begin(), arrs.end());
```

I need convert vector to set fast(linear complexity). Can i do this with use std or boost functions?

Comment: sets of raw pointers are generally not a good idea.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I havent other ways.

Comment: I need create set with possible make (xor, or, and) and (merge,subst,erase).

Comment: Need some way to do fast convert.
I havent found any ways to fast create.

Comment: The problem is that STL is slow or that you can't use STL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is already sorted, then you could use the `insert`-variant with a `hint` and "tell" the insert operation to start the search at the end (cf. [multiset::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert)):

```
iterator insert( iterator hint, const value_type& value )
```

> ** Complexity **
>   Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just after the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.

Hence, something like the following loop should do the job in about linear complexity (provided that `arrs` is sorted):

```
for (auto t : arrs) {
  tr.insert(tr.end(), t);   
}
```